# Calling index number location using PHP

Tags: php

I've got a bit of a problem, I have 2 inputs, one to type words, the other to find a keyword in the word array,

My code looks like this

```
if (isset($_POST['ord'])){
    $name = $_POST['ord'];
    $searchWord = $_POST['sök'];
    $nameArray = (explode(" ", $name));

    foreach ($nameArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === $searchWord) {
            echo substr_count($name, $value) ;
            echo "<br>";
            echo  array_keys($value, $name);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is with this line
`echo array_keys($value, $name);`

I can only get it to call out the position of the index once before it stops, I want it to call out all the index positions, In this cause it would be 2 and 4

It might also have to do with the break; but then the problem remains that the break prevents the first line to repeat which is why I added it

This is what the output looks like (Can't post image yet)

Array ( [0] => hi [1] => Hey [2] => hi [3] => Hey )
The word Hey was found 2 times

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\wamp64\www\labb-1a-php-sidor\sida3.php on line 39

Comment: Don't post a screenshot, post the text.

Comment: Can you add sample input and the desired output?

Comment: You can't echo an array. You should use `var_dump(array_keys(...));`

Comment: `array_keys($value, $name);` makes no sense. `$value` is a string, not an array.

Comment: Where is the first part of the output coming from? There's nothing in the code you posted that prints that message.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to switch position of $value, and $name, but still getting an error. also I did the var_dump, which still produced an error msg

Comment: I changed the message to make it simpler for people to read just the code, since the message is written in swedish

Comment: But the code you posted doesn't print the message in any language.

Comment: The full raw code would look something like this ```if (isset($_POST['ord'])){
$name = $_POST['ord'];
$searchWord = $_POST['sök'];
$nameArray = (explode(" ", $name));

print_r($nameArray);
echo "<br>";


foreach ($nameArray as $key => $value) {

if ($value === $searchWord) {

echo "Ordet ". $value .' hittades ' . substr_count($name, $value) . " gånger";
echo "<br>";

echo "Ordet ". $value .' Finns på plats: ' . array_keys($value,$value) . " gånger";

break;
}

}

}``` 

So when the searchWord, and value match, the code executes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. Just call `array_keys()` correctly -- the first argument should be the array.

```
if (isset($_POST['ord'])){
    $name = $_POST['ord'];
    $searchWord = $_POST['sök'];
    $nameArray = (explode(" ", $name));

    $result = array_keys($nameArray, $searchWord);
    echo "The word $searchWord was found " . count($result) . " times<br>";
    var_dump($result);
}
```